# MVC5 Identity Seed Users in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am getting an error that says: "UserId not found." when trying to seed multiple users into my database.

Here is my seed method:

```
protected override void Seed(newBestPlay.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.
    InitialCreate create = new InitialCreate();
    create.Down();
    create.Up();
    context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

    if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Admin"))
    {
        var store = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
        var manager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(store);
        var role = new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin" };
        manager.Create(role);
    }

    if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "User"))
    {
        var store = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
        var manager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(store);
        var role = new IdentityRole { Name = "User" };
        manager.Create(role);
    }

    if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "user1"))
    {
        var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "user1", Email = "email1" };
        manager.Create(user, "ChangeItAsap!");
        manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
    }

    if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "user2"))
    {
        var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "user2", Email = "email2" };
        manager.Create(user, "ChangeItAsap!");
        manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
    }
}
```

It is failing on that last "manager.AddToRole" line.  I figured out the second user isn't even getting added to the database, so it can't find a user.Id since it never got added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  It was not allowing dashes in my username.  My username(email) has a dash in the domain part.  I had to add in

```
this.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(this) { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false };
```

into my IdentityConfig.cs file into the ApplicationUserManager constructor so it now looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {
            this.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(this) { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false };
        }
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

add this into your seed method:

```
var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);

  manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,

            };
```